# Which org.apache.http is android using? And where can i get that as a jar?

Tags: android, apache, http

At the moment I'm trying to build some integration tests for an android project. I would like to use the same apache http classes I use on the android. Which version is this and can I get a jar of that somewhere?

Trying to use the jar that comes with android only resolves in Exceptions... But most of the tests won't need running them in the emulator all the time just because I use some apache libraries or do they?

Comment: Surely you're running the integration tests on a device (or emulator), so can just create an Android test project and build against the Android libraries as usual?

Comment: they are tests for the web backend... I hoped to simply reuse the code already written in the application and run it but without all the android dependencies... The org.apache.http stuff wasn't written only for android was it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get HttpClient from the [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/index.html) site. Generally speaking, Android uses a current-generation (i.e., 4.x) version of this library. However, there may not be a published JAR that matches the code Android is using.